# Print first 20 nodes of a tree

Tags: c++, tree

Ok so I'm working on my first tree and I need to adjust it to print out the first 20 nodes of a tree. My Inorder, Preorder, and Postorder full prints are working flawlessly but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the print to stop after the first 20 nodes printed.

```
void printino(tnode *c, int cnt)
{
    if (c == NULL)
        return;
    if (cnt < 20)
    {
        cnt++;
        printino(c->lchild, cnt);
        cout << c->val << " " << cnt << endl;
        printino(c->rchild, cnt);
    }
}
```

is what I did in attempt to stop the print after 20 nodes. My count is clearly not working as it still prints every node. I added a line to cout my count and its not working correctly.

Sample output is as follows:

```
17 7
18 8
19 6
20 5
21 7
22 6
```

with the first number being the value of the node and the 2nd number being my count. I'm going to be honest and say I'm not really sure what I'm counting or why/when/how its resetting.

From what I can tell, its counting the depth of the node in the tree? not how many nodes have been printed?

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: If you write out the function calls with the argument values on a piece of paper, you'll see what your problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Change the type of param "int cnt" to "int & cnt", using reference param

Arguments can be passed to a function by two methods, They are. pass by value; pass by reference. If pass by value, the value changed inside the function never affect the real value outside the function. So if you wanna to count the size of printed nodes, you should use method pass by reference.

Comment: An explanation of what the problem was and why this solves it would make the answer a lot better.

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Can you explain why reference is needed here instead of value?

Comment: I think when you pass by refrence it does not change when the recursive calling run, but if you variable has a normal value it change in every recursive calling.(if it is not correct tell me to deete this plz :D)

Comment: Arguments can be passed to a function by two methods, They are. pass by value; pass by reference.  If pass by value, the value changed inside the function never affect the real value outside the function. So if you wanna to count the size of printed nodes, you should use method pass by reference.

Comment: Thanks moon! That is what I was looking for. I THOUGHT I understood passing by value vs reference but apparently not as when explained this feels like a pretty silly mistakes. Thanks for the help and taking the time to explain to me just where I went wrong!

Comment: @Dyft maybe to make it even clearer why a reference is needed you can actually draw the tree and see why it doesn't work without it. because when you get to a fork in the tree you pass the same count value to every branch, so every branch increases the count for itself, not a global counter. :)

Answer (score -1):

In simplest terms, you can do something like below :-

```
void printInorder(tnode *root, int k, int cnt)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        printInorder(root->left, k, cnt);

        if(cnt <  k)
        {
            cout << root->data;
            ++cnt;
        }

        printInorder(root->right, k, cnt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

move cnt++ to after printing left son:

```
void printino(tnode *c, int cnt)
{
    if (c == NULL)
        return;
    if (cnt < 20)
    { 
        printino(c->lchild, cnt);
        cnt++;
        cout << c->val << " " << cnt << endl;
        printino(c->rchild, cnt);
    }
}
```